# when I press enter, it goes directly to the response error interceptor, not request error interceptor

Tags: angularjs

I made two interceptors, request and response, and I can go there when I debug it which is great to know this is functioning. But while not filling out the required fields in the form and pressing **enter** key, then it goes to **response interceptor** straight, so I can't catch if the user pressed **enter** key using JavaScript. 
I tried by putting **(keydown.enter)==$event.preventDefault()** in the form and it didn't work.

The code below is a kind of snippet that I have test if it goes here.

```
.factory("requestErrorInterceptor",
            [
                "$q", "$injector", function ($q, $injector) {
                    return {
                        request: function (request) {

                            console.log("from request"+request)


                        },
                        requestError: function (request) {

                            return 
                            console.log("from requestError "+request);
                        }
                    }
                }
            ])
```

Comment: code, logs, screenshots? something?

Comment: As nobalG points out, please post a reproducible example

Comment: This code looks like a defective [$http service interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors). How is that related to a keydown event handler?